# How to sort dates with moment.js in array as descending order

Tags: reactjs, firebase, sorting, pagination, momentjs

Trying to make pagination,

I have an array like below so

[https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iNsIKZs8IyZbm8M1N77PAkTjqSqFugKo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L81H2.png)

In the array, there is createdAt object about time when created formatted by moment.js

which I wanna sort as descending order so that newest posts coming up first

postActions.js

```
firestore
  .collection("posts")
  .add({
    ...post,
    authorFirstName: profile.firstName,
    authorLastName: profile.lastName,
    authorId: authorId,
    createdAt: new Date()
  })
```

postReducer.js

```
case STORE_POSTS_SUCCESS:
  const snapshot = action.payload;
  const array = [];
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    //  console.log(doc);
    //  console.log(doc.id);
    array.push({
      id: doc.id,
      authorId: doc.data().authorId,
      authorFirstName: doc.data().authorFirstName,
      authorLastName: doc.data().authorLastName,
      title: doc.data().title,
      content: doc.data().content,
      createdAt: moment(doc.data().createdAt.toDate()).format(
        "MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"
      )
    });
  });

  console.log(array);
  return {
    ...state,
    //  posts: array.slice(0)
    posts: array
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're formatting your date with moment is actually pretty bad for sorting.  That string does not sort naturally in chronological order.

If you want to sort records by date, you're far better off just storing the integer value of the date at that point in time.  Integers are very easy to sort.  The typical way to store times in Realtime Database is using milliseconds since unix epoch, which is pretty universal on modern operating systems.  In JavaScript, you can get the current time with `Date.now()`.  This is strongly preferred over most other forms of date representation.